# Save each slice of a dataframe into a specific excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
print(df)
    city    Year    ville   Asset_Type  Titre   psqm
0   Agadir  2010.0  Agadir  Appart  3225    6276.923077
1   Agadir  2010.0  Agadir  Maison_Dar  37  8571.428571
2   Agadir  2010.0  Agadir  Villa   107 6279.469027
3   Agadir  2011.0  Agadir  Appart  2931    6516.853933
4   Agadir  2011.0  Agadir  Maison_Dar  33  9000.000000
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
669 Tanger  2020.0  Tanger  Maison_Dar  134 13382.653061
670 Tanger  2021.0  BeniMakada  Appart  67  5555.555556
671 Tanger  2021.0  BeniMakada  Maison_Dar  4   14533.492823
672 Tanger  2021.0  Tanger  Appart  160 6148.338940
673 Tanger  2021.0  Tanger  Maison_Dar  12  13461.538462
```

Saving the dataframe into an excel sheet is straightforward

```
df.to_excel(path_to_output+'df.xlsx')
```

I would like to save the output of each city (column `city`) in a different sheet in the same excel file. How can I do that please? I am not sure if I need to create the sheets manually in advance and then loop over each one or create them on the fly (via python)?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loop through each unique city by using a query within dataframe, in each loop use .to_excel function

```
for i in range(len(df.city.unique())):
 df[df.city==df.city.unique()[i]].to_excel(path_to_output+f'df{i}.xlsx')
```

To store into one excel with different sheets, try:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('one_excel.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')

for i in range(len(df.city.unique())):
 df[df.city==df.city.unique()[i]].to_excel(writer,sheet_name=f'df{i}',startrow=0 , startcol=0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your code is outputing one excel file per city. I am looking to output one sheet per city in a single excel file. The result of each unique city should be in a specific sheet.

Comment: editted give it a try

Comment: remember to close the file!

Answer (score 2):

This is a more pandasesque way of doing the same thing as @kaispace30098, but should be faster as we do not iterate over each group.

First the code, then an explanation

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('one_df.xlsx') as writer:
    df.groupby('city').apply(
        lambda group: group.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=group.name)
    )
```

1. We create a writer using the `with... as...` syntax as that will automatically close the file when we are done. Otherwise you will have to manually do it later.
2. Since you want to group each sheet by city, we do that with `.groupby('city')`
3. we then apply a function to each group with `.apply()` where we cast each group to the Excel write with the name of the group i.e. the name of the city.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. It outputs each city in a separate excel sheet.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path_to_output+'Index_Output.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
name=list(df.city.unique())
for i in range(len(df.city.unique())):    
    df[df.city==df.city.unique()[i]].to_excel(writer, sheet_name= name[i])

writer.save()
writer.close()
```